# Change class component state from another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i take my first steps on react.
I'm working on a gatsbyjs site, and i'm stuck on my nav component.

Following some tuts, I started creating a class component called Burger to show/hide the nav... setting props, state and bind.. no probs right now.

On another file i put my Nav functional components, using gatsbyjs "Link" component to manage links.

What i'm trying to do, is to change the state of the "Burger" component when I click on the link.

So I tried using the onClick event:

```
onClick={() => props.handleClick()}
```

it doesn't work and the error is: props.handleClick is not a function.

What im doing wrong?

thanks

```
// Burger.js
class Burger extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isOpen: false };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen,
    });
    this.state.isOpen
      ? document.body.classList.remove("nav-open")
      : document.body.classList.add("nav-open");
  };

  render() {
    const burgerState = this.state.isOpen ? open : "";

    return (
      <button className={`${burger} ${burgerState}`} onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <span className={burger__label}>Menu</span>
        <span className={burger__line}></span>
        <span className={burger__line}></span>
        <span className={burger__line}></span>
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

```
// Nav.js
const Nav = (props) => {

  return (
    <div className={nav__overlay}>
      <div className={nav__wrap}>
        <nav className={nav__primary}>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to='/' activeClassName={active} title='Home' onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/about' activeClassName={active} title='About' onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>
                About
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/contact' activeClassName={active} title='Contact' onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>
                Contact
              </Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to='/blog' activeClassName={active} title='Blog' onClick={() => props.handleClick()}>
                Blog
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <div className='contact'>
          <ul>
            <li>aaa</li>
            <li>aaa</li>
            <li>aaa</li>
            <li>aaa</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Do you understand what props are? You might want to look up some tutorial that explains how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the error with the Burger component or the Nav component? It's not clear how Nav.js or Burger.js are related or interact with one another. Another thing is that React doesn't care if the `nav-open` class is on the body or not, so if hooked up properly the function should be callable.

Given the error you provided — `onClick={() => props.handleClick()}` — it looks like this code is in the Nav component. Wherever you render the nav, you need to pass `handleClick` as a prop, e.g. `<Nav handleClick={myFunction} />`.

You can read more about props and how they work here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html